# Как поместить полученный материал в массив через код

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d

Всем привет! Я делаю 3d проект и столкнулся с проблемой. Это мой первый 3d проект и я не знаю как поместить полученный материал в массив через код. Есть 2 массива один массив с объектами другой пустой для материалов. Как мне сделать так чтобы при запуске игры пустой массив заполнялся материалом который стоит у объектов в другом массиве? Надеюсь понятно =)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: инициализировать массив на количество элементов равноае количеству обьектов. Вытянуть материал из каждого из обьектов и поместить в новосозданны массив. С чем конкретно возникают проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

То есть вот так:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SV_Button_OCD.Length;i++)
    {
       Mat[i] = SV_Button_OCD[i].GetComponent<Material>();
    }
```

где Mat это пустой массив материалов а SV_Button_OCD это массив материалов

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).